# Direct send Connect request to Other users using LinkedIn SDK or API

Tags: ios, iphone, linkedin-api

How do we connect to other user’s using after authentication with LinkedIn using  LinkedIn SDK or API without re-directing to LinkedIn Application or opening his/her profile in web view ?

Comment: Hi, did you get anything regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

Connecting with other users is only intended to happen within the official LinkedIn application, and not via API calls available to 3rd party applications.

The LinkedIn iOS SDK will allow you to "deep link" to a particular member within the official iOS LinkedIn app to make this experience easy for your users.